# replace parenthesis open tag or closing tag with() through javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to replace open parenthesis or close parenthesis with () but the string or integer shouldcome under the parenthesis.
 like
if i write 1234) then the result should be (1234)

```
function myFunction() {
    var n;
    var $;
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    var p = str.indexOf(")");
    var q = str.indexOf("(");
    var res = str.replace(")", "");
    var re = str.replace("(", "");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    var k = str.replace("$", "(" + "$").replace(/,$/, ".").replace(")", "(" + res + ")").replace("(", "(" + res + ")").replace(/O/g, 0).replace(/o/g, 0).replace(/g/g, 9).replace(/\s/g, "");
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = k;
 }
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Need more input... like, do you want to do this in pieces of text.. (very tricky) or just single variables (strings or `int.toString()`) (ie, first and last characters) ?

Comment: Could you show a sample of the input and the desired output?

Comment: Now if want to add $ sign for dollar in the every input like ($1234 then what should we write? is this $ sign will under come in special character range? i need the same result means if user enters ($1234 or $1234) then the result should be ($1234).

Comment: I think you just have to replace `\w` with `[\w\$]`. Don't forget to vote :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a shorter try which works with alphanumerical chars :

```
var s = '1234) (1)azerty qwer)ty(0) 1234) (5678';
s = s.replace(/\(?(\w+)\)|\((\w+)\)?/g, '($1$2)');
// "(1234) (1)azerty (qwer)ty(0) (1234) (5678)"
```

Please comment in order to guide me a little ;)